# What is the equivalent of reactive-web's flatMap in Haskell's reactive-banana?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I'm looking for the function in reactive-banana that will choose from which event stream to emit next depending on the incoming value of another event stream or signal (Behaviour ?). In the library for scala, reactive-web this is done with:

```
 flatMap[U](f: T => EventStream[U]): EventStream[U]
```

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *dynamic event switching*. Unfortunately, in that formulation, it has [many problems](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2011/05/15-frp-dynamic-event-switching.html), and so is not included in reactive-banana. However, a variant of dynamic event switching will be [added soon](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2012/01/01-frp-api-0-5.html). For now, you'll have to do without it.

In particular, `flatMap` is Scala's name for the monadic bind function; a `Monad` instance for behaviours is problematic because it provides the dynamic event switching functionality that leads to the time leak explained in the article I linked.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think is exactly what I needed. I will read them carefully.

Comment: Btw, although EventSource has a bind method it does not have a pure method, so it can't be a Monad or even an Applicative. Signal, on the other hand has a pure function so it could be Monad and Applicative, but I never checked if it complies with the properties of Monad. In reactive-banana Behavior is not a Monad, I wonder what is missing.

Comment: Well, nothing's missing, as such; it's deliberately omitted because it causes time leaks and is semantically problematic; it has the "wrong type" in a sense (the right type is given in the second post I linked to).

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to ehird's answer, I want to mention that it's often possible to avoid dynamic event switching, namely when the relevant behaviors/events are in scope at compile-time. Dynamic event switching is only needed when you compute a new behavior/event on the fly, not when you switch between behaviors/events that are already in scope.

In particular, have a look at the TwoCounters.hs example on the [examples page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples) to see how this can be done.

Comment: In the TwoCounters.hs example both counters are updated whenever the buttons up or down are pressed, it's just that the value of one of the counters will not change. I can think of many situations where this is not wanted, since emitting something could be the visible effect in itself (i.e. play a musical note). Would there be a way to change this example such that only one of the counters receives a new event when you press the up or down buttons ?

Comment: Note that the semantics of `Behavior` is different from what you expect. It does not come with any notion of "this value was updated". (There is the `changes` function, but it's only an approximation.) You have to use an `Event` if you care about "emitting" values, like playing a musical note. In the case of the counter, you can filter out the button presses from the inactive counters after they were changed.